# Disable "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings"

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, compatibility, dpi, windows-10-v1511

I'm having trouble with a few applications, particularly RuneScape, setting the compatibility option "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" every time I try to run it.

I want that option to be unchecked, but every time I run it, it checks itself.

I've been doing a lot of research on ways to fix this, and I think I'm pretty close. I was able to find [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/11/22/disabling-dpi-scaling-on-windows-8-1-the-enterprise-way.aspx) describing permanently turning ON this feature via the Registry. I was able to configure this just fine, but of course this is the exact opposite of what I want to do.

So my question is, what's the opposite of `~ HIGHDPIAWARE`, so that I can plug it in to the Registry, and permanently disable that check box for this application? I just want that checkbox empty and grayed out so that it can't set itself again.

Here are some screenshots:

*Inserting the specified registry key:*

[image: registry key in question]

*After inserting the above registry key:*

[image: checkbox with registry key]

*The goal (Photoshopped):*

[image: grayed out checkbox]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting "change settings for all users"? This should override the default behaviour for the application/shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, high dpi awareness is forced in [more than](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt843498(v=vs.85).aspx) a single place. Aside of the compatibility database, you have also the [manifest](http://surfaceproartist.com/blog/2013/12/11/hack-makes-photoshop-and-illustrator-readable-on-surface-pro) and the [program APIs](https://github.com/GeorgeHahn/DPIMangler)..

Could you try [`~ DPIUNAWARE`](https://superuser.com/a/1276743/567466)?